# Rotate RGBA image clockwise

Tags: c++, png, trigonometry

I have 1d array (size = `4 * width * height + 1`) of pixels of RGBA png image. I want to rotate image by X degrees clockwise. I already know how to do it for 90 degrees, but I guess I have some problem with trigonometry.
Here's the code:

```
std::pair<int, int> move(int x, int y, double rad) {
    return {x * cos(rad) - y * sin(rad), x * cos(rad) + y * sin(rad)};
}
void turn(int deg) {
        if (deg < 0) {
            deg = 360 + deg;
        }
        double rad = deg * (M_PI / (double)180);
        unsigned int oldWidth = width;
        width = lround(sqrt(height * height + width * width));
        height = lround(sqrt(height * height + oldWidth * oldWidth));
        std::vector<unsigned char> output(rawPixels.size());
        for (int X = 0; X < width; ++X) {
            for (int Y = 0; Y < height; ++Y) {
                for (int chan = 0; chan < CHANNELS_COUNT; ++chan) {
                    std::pair<int, int> xy = move(X, Y, rad);
                    output[(X * height + Y) * CHANNELS_COUNT + chan] = rawPixels[
                            ((height - 1 - xy.second) * width + xy.first) * CHANNELS_COUNT + chan];
                }
            }
        }
        rawPixels = output;
    }
```

It's ok to use addition arrays, but I don't want to use OpenCV or any other libraries.

Comment: What is the problem? What I can see is that you should probably rotate around the center of the image: `(x - center_x) * cos - (y - center_y) * sin + center_x` etc -- and when accessing the pixel, you should clamp the `xy` to the input dimensions -- or surround the rawPixels with large enough border.

Comment: can you please elaborate more? How do I find center?

Comment: Center = width/2, height/2

Comment: but we also need to change width and height after rotation, right? @AkiSuihkonen

Comment: I doubt that this simple technique will give you good results. I'd give a peek to existing algorithms.

Comment: It all depends what you want to achieve. You can enlarge the new width and height to be able see all pixels from the original image, or you can shrink the new width and height in order of not to see any black pixels. First -- just do it and look at the result. And yes, the result won't look probably that pretty for small images -- then you need to study e.g. bilinear interpolation.